# Navicat MySQL - Import feature screwing up my numbers

Tags: mysql, database, excel, spreadsheet

I've been wrestling with this problem for quite a while now.

A client has given me 4 spreadsheet files, all of which are just fine. Not a thing wrong with them.

They just have stuff like Part Numbers, Item names, and Prices.

Prices look something like this: 7.99 or 0.58

But when I import the spreadsheets into a new, empty database table using Navicat for MySQL, the numbers get screwed up!

Most of them look like this now: 7.9986 and 0.0580 etc etc etc!

And because there are tens of thousands of prices, and because I don't know the pricing for all of their products, I don't know sometimes which is the real price, and which is a wrong one.

I have no idea what's causing this problem.

Any help at all is greatly appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like it could be a precision problem.  What data type are you using for the price column in the "new, empty" table?  Try using DECIMAL or NUMERIC rather than (say) FLOAT, if applicable.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Although, I don't see any options whatsoever when using the import wizard of Navicat for MySQL :-S **edit**: There is, I overlooked it. I am going to give that a go now.